# Can't connect Sqlalchemy with pymssql to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy, sql-server-2000, pymssql

Using pymssql.connect it worked

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect("192.168.1.12", "sa", "123456789", "aa")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Table2')
print( "all persons" )
print( cursor.fetchall() )
```

However, I want to use SQLAlchemy with pymssql and it does not work

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://sa:123456789@192.168.1.12/aa")
df = pd.read_sql_table('Table2', engine)
df
```

> OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (195, b"'schema_name' is not a recognized function name.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
> [SQL: SELECT schema_name()]
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

How can I connect this?

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server 2000 is still supported by that driver? Why are you still using such an old version (IIRC, Microsoft stopped support back in 2005)?

Comment: [The Pymssql Project has been Discontinued](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668) and SQL Server 2000 is **long** out of support. You *need* to get that SQL Server upgraded, and you really need to look at an alternative library for Python.

Comment: Based on your first example, your SQLAlchemy connection URL should use `sa:123456789@192.168.1.12`, not `sa:@123456789@192.168.1.12`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  I'm sure  SQL Server 2000 supported by this driver if using pymssql.connect it can insert select all CRUD

Comment: ok I change to sa:123456789@192.168.1.12 and a new error is

OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (195, b"'schema_name' is not a recognized function name.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
[SQL: SELECT schema_name()]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

@GordThompson

Comment: @Larnu

I normally use postgres sqlalchemy, it connects fine without set driver, but when I connect to sql server library that need to set driver is PyODBC, mxODBC feel messed up, so I found the Pymssql library that connects without setting driver, But if Pymssql Discontinued is there any other library that is as easy to use as Pymssql?